# Finding the solution of a Differential Equation $xy''=-yy'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following initial value problem,
$$
\begin{cases}
    xy''=-yy', \; \forall x \in (0,1] \\
    y(0)=0,\\
    y'(0)=2
\end{cases}
$$
If it was linear, I would have no problems. But here I don't know what method should I use.
I have used the Euler method to find an approximation to the answer in some points. Can someone give me a hint of how to find the analytic soluction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, factor the RHS as
$$-yy' = -\frac{1}{2}\left[y^2\right]'.$$
Thus,
$$xy'' = -\frac{1}{2}\left[y^2\right]'.$$

Now, integrate both sides.  For the LHS, we use integration by parts.
$$y-xy' = \frac{1}{2}y^2 + c_1.$$

Rearranging gives us
$$-xy' = \frac{1}{2}y^2 - y + c_1.$$

At this point, separation of variables gives
$$\frac{dy}{y^2-2y+2c_1} = -\frac{dx}{x}.$$
$$\frac{dy}{(y-1)^2+2c_1-1} = -\frac{dx}{x}.$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c_1-1}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y-1}{\sqrt{2c_1-1}}\right) = -\ln(x)+c_2.$$

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y-1}{\sqrt{2c_1-1}}\right) = \sqrt{2c_1-1}(-\ln(x)+c_2).$$
$$\frac{y-1}{\sqrt{2c_1-1}} = \tan(\sqrt{2c_1-1}(-\ln(x)+c_2)).$$
$$y = 1+\sqrt{2c_1-1}\tan(\sqrt{2c_1-1}(c_2-\ln(x))).$$

Comment: Thank you.  I just did not go that far in my analysis.